# SQL Exists clause in Supabase JS Client

Tags: javascript, typescript, supabase, supabase-js

In SQL the EXISTS clause is quite useful for checking specific conditions without having to join. For example looking for a user which doesn't belong to a group :

```
SELECT * FROM users u WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM users_groups ug WHERE ug.user_id = u.id)
```

Is there an equivalent to this type of query in the Supabase Javascript Client library ? I have looked at the docs but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/3419#discussioncomment-1428126 - you most likely want a [custom sql function](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this with a traditional `` .from(...).select(`*`) ``, but the Supabase JS client can run custom RPC functions.

The end result will look something like this:

```js
const { data, error }  = await supabase.rpc('select_users_with_no_groups')
```

You'll want to define the function in Supabase:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.seleect_users_with_no_groups()
    RETURNS TABLE(id uuid, email text)
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE
    SECURITY INVOKER
    SET search_path TO 'public'
AS $function$
    SELECT (id, email) FROM users u WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM user_groups ug WHERE ug.user_id = u.id)
$function$;
```

This function honors RLS policies with the `SECURITY INVOKER` line. You'll want to customize the columns returned, but the rest should give you your desired result.